# Ubuntu 18.04 reenable SSH password prompt with git

Tags: ssh, password, git

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 where I have set up an SSH key to be used with Git. On one of the first prompts when I used the key I checked the option to stop asking me for the SSH password when my user is logged in. I want to revert on that choice so that I will be again prompted for the SSH password.

Comment: I think this is what you're asking: [SSH: Switch from public key authentication to password - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/300619/403609)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with git though. Do you mean GitHub?

Comment: The remote git server is hosted with Bitbucket, not GitHub.

Comment: Are you sure that your private key has a password set at all?

Comment: Yes, it has a password set.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar thing. I had a key that also required a password. Before I updated to 18.04, I would get a password prompt every time I used it. Now, I don't get this prompt and I get the error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 0):

In case git is using `ssh-agent` (I am guessing a bit here), you would have to issue the command

```
ssh-add -D
```

to make it forget cached credentials for all your private keys. Those credentials would have been forgotten after a reboot of the system as well.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work out.